How to default to full screen tiling when dragging to top of screen in 24.04
I just installed Budgie 24.04 and I notice a change which I do not like. Luckily, Ubuntu is great at giving the user choices but I cannot find the setting I'm looking for.
In 22.04, when you use your mouse and drag a window to the top of the screen, it will maximize the window. Now, in 24.04, the default behavior is to only show that window on the top 50% of the screen. This change to the tiling function is not great.
I do see that if I drag and hold the window at the top, it will expand to full screen, but the extra 2-3 seconds every time I do this is really frustrating. I would like to revert to the earlier behavior.
I read some pages which talked about the Extension Manager but when I search for "tiling" I get a long list of "unsupported" items.
Is there any way to change so that dragging to the top of a screen will default to maximizing the window rather than 50%?

I feel a little silly for not finding this before I posted the question but hopefully this answer will help others struggling with this issue.
The solution is go to the app Budgie Desktop Settings, go to Windows, then turn on Automatic Tiling.

That alone fixes the problem.
